# Using Windows api TimeZoneInfo ConvertTimeFromUtc

Tags: excel, vba

In powershell I can use the windows system api

```
$estzone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")
$esttime = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc($test2, $estzone)
"GMT= " +$test2 + " EST =" + $esttime
```

I can't seem to reference FindSystemTimeZoneById or ConvertTimeFromUtc in VB

I have tried

```
Option Explicit


Private Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Private Type TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Bias As Long
    StandardName(0 To 31) As Integer
    StandardDate As SYSTEMTIME
    StandardBias As Long
    DaylightName(0 To 31) As Integer
    DaylightDate As SYSTEMTIME
    DaylightBias As Long
End Type

Private Enum TIME_ZONE
    TIME_ZONE_ID_INVALID = 0        ' Cannot determine DST
    TIME_ZONE_STANDARD = 1          ' Standard Time, not Daylight
    TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT = 2          ' Daylight Time, not Standard
End Enum
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindSystemTimeZoneById Lib "kernel32" (lpTimeZone As String) As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ConvertTimeFromUtc Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As Date, pTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long


Function GetLocalTimeFromGMTerc(GMTTime As Date)
    Dim estzone As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Dim esttime As Date
    estzone = FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")
    esttime = ConvertTimeFromUtc(GMTTime, estzone)
    GetLocalTimeFromGMTerc = esttime
End Function
```

This seems to compile/run but give "A value use in the formula is of the wrong data type"
I assume I am doing it completely wrong. Any help?

Thanks!